# Git pre-commit hook not running

Tags: node.js, git, bash, pre-commit-hook

Here's my pre-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec node build.js
```

That code works fine when I change `pre-commit` to `pre-commit.sh` and run it, it also executes correctly when I just run `exec node build.js` in the terminal. The build file works fine.

Here's `build.js`:

```
var fs = require("fs")
var through2 = require('through2');
var markdownPdf = require("markdown-pdf")
var removeMarkdown = require("remove-markdown")

var resume = fs.createReadStream("README.md")
var pdf = fs.createWriteStream("Resume - Desmond Weindorf.pdf")
var txt = fs.createWriteStream("Resume - Desmond Weindorf.txt")
var md = fs.createWriteStream("Resume - Desmond Weindorf.md")

process.stdout.write('Building other file types...\n')

// pdf
resume.pipe(markdownPdf({ paperBorder: "1.4cm" })).pipe(pdf)

// txt
resume.pipe(through2(function(line, _, next) {
    this.push(removeMarkdown(line.toString()) + '\n');
    next()
})).pipe(txt)

// md
resume.pipe(md)
```

I thought it might be ending prematurely (and probably is) before the new files are written to, but the terminal should still display the initial write output in that case.

This was my output on a commit (the pdf was changed beforehand to test if it was overwriting with new changes):

```
Desmonds-MacBook-Pro:resume desmond$ git commit -am "updated resume"
[master 7faab35] updated resume
 4 files changed, 36 insertions(+), 34 deletions(-)
 rewrite Resume - Desmond Weindorf.pdf (81%)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Quick guess: the pre-commit hook is executed with PWD in the repo. So it does not know where `build.js` is. Try `exec node /path/to/build.js`.

Comment: @Mort Tried it with the full filepath and this did not resolve the issue

Comment: Debug it step-by-step. Is it called exactly `pre-commit`? Does it reside in `.git/hooks/`? Is the file executable? Add `echo pre-commit test` before `exec` to test git runs the script.

Comment: `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit` and try again

Comment: @phd @janos Thanks, that worked! What exactly did that change? Does that need to be done for every pre-commit file or only when running the `exec` command within it?

Comment: `chmod +x` makes the file executable. It needs to be done for every script, hook or not hook.

Comment: You might need to specify the full path to the node executable.